# Canvas HTML5. Случайные линии

Tags: javascript, canvas, рисование

Решил написать функцию рисования случайных линий:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function createRandomLine() {
    var beginRandX = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
  var beginRandY = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
  var endRandX = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
  var endRandY = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(beginRandX, beginRandY);
  ctx.lineTo(endRandX, endRandY);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

И привязал к canvas:

```
<canvas id = "canvas" width=600 height=500 onclick = "createRandomLine()"> 
</canvas>
```

Но по клику ничего не отображается.

Comment: Атрибуты нужно задавать в скобках width="600" height="500" и вместо onclick клик лучше давать через addEventListener или onclick через свойство в js.

Answer (score 0):

Вы попадаете по канвасу, когда кликаете?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function createRandomLine() {
  var beginRandX = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
  var beginRandY = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
  var endRandX = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
  var endRandY = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(beginRandX, beginRandY);
  ctx.lineTo(endRandX, endRandY);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" onclick="createRandomLine()"></canvas>
```

Comment: может быть мне лучше добавить атрибут onclick в body?

Comment: вы действительно не видите в моем варианте ошибок?